# Is the PDF library that Microsoft uses in Excel available to the outside world?

Tags: winapi, pdf, pdf-generation

Excel 2010 (and Word 2010, probably others) have the ability to save directly to a PDF:

[image]

and they print it [without](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHYQFjAA&url=http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php&ei=7UO9T9qJPMXs2QXS6OmiDw&usg=AFQjCNGjJSQtlBOF5mNvye6asSvdoRP1lw&sig2=c5bRbLUwvCGDX0m-pXgM9g) [installing](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CH0QFjAB&url=http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/&ei=7UO9T9qJPMXs2QXS6OmiDw&usg=AFQjCNH8WJ3bow67eCjeG-gQ-xpeyLniEg&sig2=Kn4A2Vsg2_LYfvF5wN_DIg) [a](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CH8QFjAC&url=http://www.cutepdf.com/&ei=7UO9T9qJPMXs2QXS6OmiDw&usg=AFQjCNFAloTzoYbYBLjfEYvNA9q4-GyADQ&sig2=NrWgnfF41xJpXmWaw_aLiw) ["PDF printer"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CI8BEBYwBw&url=http://pdfprinter.com/&ei=7UO9T9qJPMXs2QXS6OmiDw&usg=AFQjCNF-MVJerGTSZmvsKzloKmLLN_bbzA&sig2=XRwFsn3O_oDpQDKdj33f2w).

Is the PDF library Microsoft is using to generate PDFs available to the outside world?

- a COM object?
- a codeplex open-source project?

**tl;dr:** How is Microsoft creating PDFs from native Win32 applications?

Comment: The ASP.Net ReportViewer control, which displays reports generated as .rdl or .rdlc files, also automagically provides the ability to export to PDF or Excel or Word.

Comment: FWIW Having done this with office automation I recall that it was exp_pdf.dll that was required (that's what the demo code detects for pdf support; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834871(v=office.11).aspx) this however only seems to have a single export as required for the office "fixed format" extensibility feature.

Comment: I'm using office automation in a asp.net page to get Access reports from my ASPX page in PDF format. It works fine an a windows server 2003, but it doesn't on a windows server 2008 64bit. I'm using DoCmd.OutputTo to generate pdf, and the problem seems to be in the exp_pdf.dll

Answer (score 1):

ABCpdf boasts Microsoft uses their product. Don't know how and where does Microsoft uses it, but it sure seems to be good pdf library.

http://www.websupergoo.com/aboutus.htm